# Update Statement After Dynamic SQL Not Updating Everything

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the statement as:

```
set @cmd = '
exec pr_sys_drop_object ''ztb_staging_Demand_prep''

select *
into ztb_staging_Demand_prep                                         
from ndcaspsqlp01.[source table] A

' 
--print @cmd
exec(@cmd)

;Update A
set A.Material_CD = B.Planning_Material_CD
from ztb_staging_Demand_prep A
inner join ztb_planning_material_mapping b on A.Material_Cd = B.material_CD
```

However, searching within the table `ztb_staging_Demand_prep` for a material that should have been mapped in the update, the material_cd, some material_cd are still present. I know this because if I simply run:

```
Update A
    set A.Material_CD = B.Planning_Material_CD
    from ztb_staging_Demand_prep A
    inner join ztb_planning_material_mapping b on A.Material_Cd = B.material_CD
```

afterward, those materials that should have been updated, no longer appear, which is correct.

I know SQL is synchronous, but why/how could the model not update? Is there a setting so that the update only occurs after the `exec()` has completed

**I have variables defined before this section that need to be accessed after that statement**

Comment: Why dont we push the update statement into the dynamic query?

Comment: Running this update once or twice may cause different pictures depending on data. So I think your statement may not prove that there is a problem .

Comment: I attempted adding the update statement within the dynamic sql but it did not improve

Comment: @Sauron, I guess because there is no corresponding row in mapping table. Try `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: The row exists in the mapping table

Comment: Then it's impossible to have not updated rows. Unless there is another update or rollback later. Or trigger.

Comment: @SerifEmek Can you please elaborate on your comment. I have run the procedure and it worked the first time how the update should. Is there some sort of catching that needs to be cleared? What can "cause different pictures of data"?

Comment: I may misunderstand the case. I see that: 1)you run the script with update. 2)you run update only. After 2(running update only) ztb_staging_Demand_prep changes. My point is that the change may not mean update of first step didnt execute. Because material_CD column updated too. Every time you run the update a different mapping can be found.